# IF Statement For Session - Formatting Q

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So I have this IF statement in my view. it works and all, but wondering if there's a better way to write this. Having both session calls seem unneccessary...

```
if($this->session->userdata('campaign_name')){
    echo $this->session->userdata('campaign_name');
}
else {
    echo 'this';
}
```

**Note** this function will be used inline on a text input. So I'm looking for as minimal code as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that CI's Session class's userdata method will return false if no `campaign_name` exists. So assign a variable to the potentially undefined array key (campaign_name)

```
$campaign_name = $this->session->userdata('campaign_name');

if($campaign_name)
{
    echo $campaign_name;
}
else
{
    echo 'this';
}
```

**OR**

```
if($campaign_name = $this->session->userdata('campaign_name'))
{ 
   echo $campaign_name;
}
```

**Controller Method** (/application/controllers/test_controller.php)

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }
        public function myFunction()
        {
            $data['campaign_name'] = $this->session->userdata('campaign_name');
            $this->load->view('test_view',$data);

        }
    }
```

**View** (/application/view/test_view.php)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <input type="text" value="<?php echo $campaign_name; ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be best for an inline option? (i.e. on a text input..). trying to avoid all this code for an inline function.

Comment: @MikeBarwick it would be best to have this controlled in the controller.

Comment: Nice...I know the controller route...thing this would be the ideal solution. I'll hammer this out. Cheers!!!

Comment: Hmm, I tried something to the above, but no worky. Undefined variable in the view...can you have a look? What am I doing wrong? Here's my PasteBin http://pastebin.com/3RbzcEda

Comment: just load the view as a string, don't use the data['x'] variable to load the view

Comment: try defining the variable to the session function before the if statement then use the variable in the if statement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19849/discussion-between-rpm-and-mike-barwick)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you can store the value of that session data into a variable and pass that along to the view. In the view, you can then have your if else statements that just look at the variable. I would advise against setting a variable in the view as RPM did. While it works, it breaks the separation of concerns you have going.

Also, look into using the [alternative PHP syntax](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html) for views in CodeIgniter. It'll make your code neater and more maintainable.

Edit: I see now that RPM has updated his answer to set the variable in the controller. That's a good example to follow.

Comment: Thanks I might do it this way...and I already use alternative PHP syntax...something many CI's hate...I don't.

Comment: I honestly do not like using the alternative PHP syntax

Comment: I don't fully use it myself...just remove the `php` tag really

Comment: I didn't mean the use of short tags. You can do things like:
    <?php if ($username == 'sally'): ?>
    <h1><?=$username?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>